# I would like to acces the url of a web app published from a google spreadsheet without ssl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From a small appliance, not capable of SSL, I would like to update data in a [google](http://www.google.com) spreadsheet. Using [this script](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/02/collecting-any-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-get-or-post-by-publishing-as-a-service-dev8d/) I can submit the data - but only using SSL (via the URL https://script.google.com/a/macros/...).

Is there any possibility to access the same published web app script, but without SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SSL is always required to access a script.